# After re-installing ubuntu 13.10, stuck at GRUB Rescue, Boot-Repair didn't work!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, grubrescue

Because i could not get the WiFi login work, i thought i will reinstall ubuntu, with internet connection to have updated drivers for wireless & graphics etc.

I have deleted earlier linux partitions usings gparted and re-installed ubuntu 13.10, exactly following the same steps as i did earlier, making a 100GB /home on dev/sda and pointing root to /dev/sdb (SSD) and swap on dev/sda/ . Installing boot on /dev/sdb.

But, somehow i think the grub is either corrupted or removed because i am unable to boot the laptop to any OS now.

I get the following message: 
"no such device"  xxxxx followed by huge HEX number
GRUB rescue>

when i type ls on Grub rescue> prompt, i can see hd0 & hd1, but thats about it. i tried Boot-repair but it is unable to fix the problem. The following log is generated via boot-repair create log:

[Boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6326504/)

I am unable to boot into windows or linux at the moment and need help to fix the grub so i can boot !!

Comment: Please boot with LiveCD and add the output of `lsblk`,`sudo blkid /dev/sda`, `sudo blkid /dev/sdb`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

So, i have tried Boot-Repair again, but this time in a different way. I downloaded the [bootable boot-repair iso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and made a usb disk. Then boot into it, connect to internet and start "Recommended Repair".

This time, it took me through a series of steps, asked me to manually delete/uninstall grub and then re-install a new version on sda & sdb. After the repair. i could successfully have a dual boot setup, without loosing any data !! This was AWESOME.. thanks to the easy tool "boot-repair"

In case anyone has a similar issue, i would recommend them to try boot-repair first and then look for an alternate solution. Again, like in my case, it is better to have a bootable boot-repair usb rather than running it from bootable ubuntu disk.